# Unable to connect to the proxy server when Fiddler is switched off

Tags: proxy, fiddler

I have installed Fiddler.

I have following problem:

When I switch on PC Fiddler doesn't work and I don't want to start it with Windows start. I trying to go to the URL. And I see following message:

```
unable to connect to the proxy server
```

Is it possible to configure Fiddler that if it works - I see intercepted requests and web pages but if it doesn't work - browser works as well and I see web pages

Comment: Are you using some firewall software?

Comment: No, I stopped standart windows firewall

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before and searched the fiddler document and found this.

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/Proxy

It apparently that fiddler closed but didn't unregister itself successfully. 
what you can do is from the **Internet Explorer** main menu, click **Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Setting > Advanced**, then clear the proxy setting.